Showing $2(b-c)^2(d-a)^2 = (a-b)(a-c)(b-d)(c-d)$, given $(a+b)(c+d) = 2ab+2cd$
I recently came across this question:

Let $a, b, c \text{ and } d $ be non-zero constants such that $(a+b)(c+d) = 2ab+2cd$.
Show that the following identity holds:
$$2(b-c)^2(d-a)^2 = (a-b)(a-c)(b-d)(c-d)$$

I tried to approach this problem by expanding both the LHS and RHS of the desired identity and then somehow using the given identity to cancel out some terms and show that the LHS is exactly equal to the RHS, as shown below:
$$\begin{align}
\underline{\text{LHS }}: 2(b-c)^2(d-a)^2 &= 2\left(b^2-2bc+c^2\right)\left(d^2-2ad+a^2\right)\\
&=2b^2d^2-4ab^2d+2a^2b^2-4bcd^2+8abcd-4a^2bc+2c^2d^2-4ac^2d+2a^2c^2
\end{align}$$
$$\begin{align}
\underline{\text{RHS}}: (a-b)(a-c)(b-d)(c-d) &= \left(a^2-ac-ab+bc\right)\left(bc-bd-cd+d^2\right)\\
&= a^2bc-a^2bd-a^2c^2+a^2cd+ac^3-ac^2d-ab^2c+ab^2d+b^2c^2-b^2cd-bc^3+bc^2
\end{align}$$
Then from the given identity, we have that:
$$\begin{align}
(a+b)^2(c+d)^2 &= (2ab+2cd)^2\\
a^2b^2+a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2+2(a^2cd+abc^2+abd^2+b^2cd)+4abcd &=2a^2b^2+8abcd+4c^2d^2\\
a^2d^2+b^2c^2+b^2d^2+2(a^2cd+abd^2+b^2cd) &= a^2b^2+4abcd+4c^2d^2
\end{align}$$
This expansion seems to share some similar terms with the LHS of the desired identity, but seems to only produce more irrelevant terms when substituted into the LHS, and so is probably not the right approach to the problem... Apart from just brute expansion, I am not able to think of any other approach.
I would greatly appreciate it if anyone would be able to share any other approach that may work for this problem. Thanks in advance!

If $(a+b)(c+d)=2ab+2cd$ does it not mean that $(a-b)(c-d)=-2ab-2cd$?

@RedFive No, it doesn't.

Consider $a,b,c$ as polynomial indeterminates, and define the rational fraction $d\in\Bbb Q(a,b,c)$ by $(a+b)(c+d)=2ab+2cd$, i.e.
$$d:=\frac{2ab-ac-bc}{a+b-2c}.$$
Substituting $d$ in the identity we want to prove, we obtain:
$$\begin{align}2(b-c)^2(d-a)^2&= (a-b)(a-c)(b-d)(c-d)\\\iff2(b-c)^2[ab+ac-bc-a^2]^2&=(a-b)(a-c)(-ab-bc+ac+b^2)(-2ab+2bc+2ac-2c^2)\\\iff(b-c)^2[(a-b)(c-a)]^2&=(a-b)(a-c)[(b-c)(b-a)][(b-c)(c-a)]\\\iff\text{ true.}
\end{align}$$
Magic afterthought
In $\Bbb Z[a,b,c,d]$ (where $a,b,c,d$ are now four polynomial indeterminates), let $$P:=(a+b)(c+d)-2ab-2cd\quad\text{and}\quad Q:=(a+c)(b+d)-2ac-2bd.$$
You may check that
$$PQ=2(b-c)^2(d-a)^2-(a-b)(a-c)(b-d)(c-d).$$

Ahh that is a nice solution!
